# Store OrderedDict Values to Set in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, splunk, ordereddictionary

In the [Python Splunk SDK](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-python) the [ResultsReader object](http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/PythonSDK/1.1/results.html#module-splunklib.results) provides an iterable object that returns an OrderedDict when accessed. I would like to store the values contained within that OrderedDict to a set to perform set subtraction against a list of expected values. I am having trouble finding a way to access the values in the OrderedDict in a way that allows me to store them to a set.

Code example:

```
kwargs_search = {"exec_mode": "normal"}
searchquery = "search index=* earliest=-1d| stats values(host)"

job = service.jobs.create(searchquery, **kwargs_search)
for result in results.ResultsReader(job.results()):
    print result
```

Returns:

```
OrderedDict([('values(host)', ['host1', 'host2', ... 'hostN'])])
```

The `'hostN'` values are those that I would like to store in the set.

I've tried:

```
actual_hosts = set()
for result in results.ResultsReader(job.results()):
    actual_hosts.add(result)
```

Which returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'OrderedDict'
```

What is the best way to accomplish what I'm attempting here? Open to any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each of the values in your `OrderedDict` is a list (as in the example posted), then `results.values()` is a list (or iterable, in python3) of lists. In this case, you can iteratively add them to the set:

```
actual_hosts = set()
for result in results.ResultsReader(job.results()):
    for hosts in results.values():
        actual_hosts.update(hosts)
```

If each of the values is a string, the inner loop is not necessary, and you can add `results.values()` to the set directly:

```
actual_hosts = set()
for result in results.ResultsReader(job.results()):
    actual_hosts.update(results.values())
```

Comment: So, I think this is very, very close to what I'm looking for. Your first method results in the following set being created:
`set(['host1',... 'hostN']) ` which appears to be a list within the set. `'host1' in actual_hosts` returns `False` in this case. 

Your second method returns the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`, so I take it I need to also retrieve all list elements before storing to the set.

Comment: `set(['host1',... 'hostN'])` is the standard set representation, it is *not* a list inside the set. `'host1' in actual_hosts` should be `True` if that's what you're getting... The second example would work if the the structure of your OrderedDict was different, so it is not relevant (I wasn't sure at first what the structure was, so I included the second example).

Comment: Thanks, you were absolutely right, ran through it with a debugger and was able to get the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`result.values()` should give you the part `['host1',..`

Answer (score 0):

An example of creating a set from the values of a `dict` (it's the same with an `OrderedDict`):

```
d = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [2, 3, 4]
}

hosts = set().union(*d.itervalues())
# set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Which then extends to:

```
from itertools import chain
hosts = set().union(*chain.from_iterable(res.values() for res in results.ResultsReader(job.results())))
```

The explicit loop and update is nicer though :)